R-Squared From CV is way higher than without CV in XGBoost
I have this code of a XGBoost model:
temp_dataset_pos = dataset_vehicle_pos.copy()
# temp_dataset_pos = temp_dataset_pos.drop(['sum_passenger'], axis=1)
# temp_dataset_pos = temp_dataset_pos[['humidity','temperature', 'vehicle_avg_speed_pos']]

X_pos = temp_dataset_pos.drop('vehicle_avg_speed_pos', axis=1)
y_pos = temp_dataset_pos['vehicle_avg_speed_pos']

# Split the data into train and test sets
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X_pos, y_pos, test_size=0.20, random_state=42)

# Create an XGBoost model
xgboost_model = xgb.XGBRegressor(objective='reg:squarederror', random_state=42)  # You can adjust hyperparameters

# Fit the model
xgboost_model.fit(X_train, y_train)
# Ensure the predicted data aligns with the test set
X_test['vehicle_count_pos'] = predicted_vehicle_count_pos['predicted_vehicle_count_pos']

# Make predictions on the test set
y_pred_xgboost = xgboost_model.predict(X_test)

# Round the predicted values to integers
y_pred_rounded = y_pred_xgboost.round().astype(int)

# Evaluate the model
mse_xgboost = mean_squared_error(y_test, y_pred_rounded)
print(f'Mean Squared Error (XGBoost): {mse_xgboost}')
r2_xgboost = r2_score(y_test, y_pred_rounded)
print('R-squared value:', r2_xgboost)
importance = xgboost_model.feature_importances_


# Create an XGBoost model
xgboost_model = xgb.XGBRegressor(objective='reg:squarederror', random_state=42)  # You can adjust hyperparameters

# Define a K-Fold cross validator
kf = KFold(n_splits=5, shuffle=True, random_state=42)

# Define the scorer based on Mean Squared Error
mse_scorer = make_scorer(mean_squared_error, greater_is_better=False)

# Perform cross-validation and calculate MSE
mse_scores = cross_val_score(xgboost_model, X_pos, y_pos, scoring=mse_scorer, cv=kf)

# Convert MSE scores to positive; cross_val_score returns negative values for 'greater_is_better=False'
mse_scores = -mse_scores

# Calculate mean and standard deviation of MSE
mean_mse = np.mean(mse_scores)
std_mse = np.std(mse_scores)

print(f'Mean MSE from CV: {mean_mse}')
print(f'Std MSE from CV: {std_mse}\n')

# If you also want to include R-squared in your results summary
r2_scorer = 'r2'
r2_scores = cross_val_score(xgboost_model, X_pos, y_pos, scoring=r2_scorer, cv=kf)

mean_r2 = np.mean(r2_scores)
std_r2 = np.std(r2_scores)

print(f'Mean R-squared from CV: {mean_r2}')
print(f'Std R-squared from CV: {std_r2}')
print('\n')

And I get these results:
Mean Squared Error (XGBoost): 395.3362869635255 
R-squared value: 0.37072522417952525
Mean MSE from CV: 6.902625450153782
Std MSE from CV: 0.8885273860917627
Mean R-squared from CV: 0.990070278719086
Std R-squared from CV: 0.000623638887270274
How come that the R-Squared is so different with and without CV?
Am I missing something in my code?
